# Jest testing of async middleware for authentication

Tags: express, async-await, jestjs, currying

I'm using a static array to scaffold a user table, prior to refactoring with actual postgres db and some `fetch()`-ing code. At present, the tests work, but obviously they are working synchronously. Here's the placeholder API code:

```js
    // UserAPI.js
    let findUserById = (credentials = {}) => {
      const { userId } = credentials
    
      if (userId) {
        const foundUser = users.find(user => user.id === userId)
        if (foundUser !== undefined) {
          const { password: storedpassword, ...user } = foundUser
          return user
        }
      }
      return null
    }
    exports.byId = findUserById
```

And an example test as follows:

```js
    // excerpt from TokenAuth.test.js
    const UserAPI = require('../lib/UserAPI')
    
    describe('With TokenAuth middleware', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        setStatus(0)
      })
    
      it('should add user to req on authorised requests', () => {
        const token = createToken(fakeUser)
        const authReq = { headers: { authorization: 'Bearer ' + token } }
        const myMiddleware = TokenAuth(UserAPI.byId)
        myMiddleware(authReq, fakeRes, fakeNext)
    
        // expect(authReq.user).toStrictEqual({ id: 1, username: 'smith@example.com' });
        expect(authReq.user.username).toStrictEqual('smith@example.com')
        expect(authReq.user.id).toStrictEqual(1)
      })
    })
```

This runs fine, and along with other tests gives me the coverage I want. However, I now want to check that the tests will deal with the `async/await` nature of the `fetch()` code I'm going to use for the proper `UserAPI.js` file. So I re-write the placeholder code as:

```js
    // UserAPI.js with added async/await pauses ;-)
    let findUserById = async (credentials = {}) => {
      const { userId } = credentials
    
      // simulate url resolution
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 100)) // avoid jest open handle error
    
      if (userId) {
        const foundUser = users.find(user => user.id === userId)
        if (foundUser !== undefined) {
          const { password: storedpassword, ...user } = foundUser
          return user
        }
      }
      return null
    }
    exports.byId = findUserById
```

... at which point I start getting some lovely failures, due I think it's returning unresolved promises.

My problem is two-fold:

1. How should I alter the `UserAPI.test.js` tests to deal with the new `async` nature of `findUserByCredentials()` ?
2. Am I ok in my assumption that ExpressJS is happy with async functions as request handlers? Specifically, due to the `async` nature of`UserAPI.findUserByCredentials`  is this ok?

Main `App.js` uses curried `UserAPI.byId()` for the `findUserById`.

```js
    // App.js (massively simplified)
    const express = require('express')
    const TokenAuth = require('./middleware/TokenAuth')
    const RequireAuth = require('./middleware/RequireAuth')
    const UserAPI = require('./lib/UserAPI')
    
    let router = express.Router()
    const app = express()
    
    app.use(TokenAuth(UserAPI.byId))
    app.use(RequireAuth)
    app.use('/users', UserRouter)
    module.exports = app
```

My TokenAuth middleware would now run along these lines:

```js
    // TokenAuth.js (simplified)
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
    require('dotenv').config()
    const signature = process.env.SIGNATURE
    
    let TokenAuth = findUserById => async (req, res, next) => {
      let header = req.headers.authorization || ''
      let [type, token] = header.split(' ')
      if (type === 'Bearer') {
        let payload
        try {
          payload = jwt.verify(token, signature)
        } catch (err) {
          res.sendStatus(401)
          return
        }
    
        let user = await findUserById(payload)
        if (user) {
          req.user = user
        } else {
          res.sendStatus(401)
          return
        }
      }
    
      next()
    }
    
    module.exports = TokenAuth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer us simply to add an async/await on the `middleware` call:

```js
  it('should add user to req on authorised requests', async () => {
    const token = createToken(fakeUser)
    const authReq = { headers: { authorization: 'Bearer ' + token } }
    const myMiddleware = TokenAuth(UserAPI.byId)
    await myMiddleware(authReq, fakeRes, fakeNext)

    // expect(authReq.user).toStrictEqual({ id: 1, username: 'smith@example.com' });
    expect(authReq.user.username).toStrictEqual('smith@example.com')
    expect(authReq.user.id).toStrictEqual(1)
  })
```